# In Django 1.7 ModelMultipleChoiceField specify/filter all related subtasks must share a project

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to filter my `Task` form so that when you select any subtasks, they must share the 'super-tasks' project.

Here's a simple look on my task and dependency model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', related_name="tasks")
    dependency = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Dependency', null=True, 
        blank=True, through_fields=('task', 'sub_task'), symmetrical=False)

class Dependency(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name="dependency_task")
    sub_task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name="dependency_sub_task")
```

And this is what I'm 'trying to get away with' on my form:

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    subtasks=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=
                                    Task.objects.filter(project=task.project))
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        exclude = ('project',)
```

I mean it looks like the right 'sort' of thing, but PyLint says it doesn't recognise 'task'.

If I try to get the task by saving, PyLint also warns me it won't work:

```
 task = forms.ModelForm.save(commit=False)
```

PyLint is expecting a 'self' argument in the save method, but one doesn't exist.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`task` variable is not available at the time of `TaskForm` definition.  You should set up subtask's queryset in the constructor:

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):

    subtasks=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Task.objects.none())

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        exclude = ('project',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance and self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['subtasks'].queryset = Task.objects.filter(
                                               project=self.instance.project)
```

To pass current task to the form use `instance` argument:

```
form = TaskForm(instance=Task.objects.get(pk=1))
```

Comment: Where does the `self.instance` and `self.instance.pk` come from? Are they part of the `super.__init__` method? Would they ever not exist?

Comment: Regardless this works perfectly. It's a shame Django doesn't allow this to be done is a nicer way though.

Comment: Pass `instance` argument to the form's constructor.

Comment: I don't follow, is that an answer to my question(s)? Or something I should do?

Comment: Yes, this is the answer to your question.  See the example of form creation in the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, It 'seems' like it's working even when I don't specify an instance to the form, in that when I got to my `task_edit.html` I can only select other tasks from the same project. My problem is that the choices don't seem to persist. I know if you use `save(commit=False)` you also need a `save_m2m`...but I don't see a `save(commit=False)`. Is one being called in the super call? If so where do I put the extra save, in the `TaskForm` class, or the `__init__` def? Sorry if these are stupid questions.

Comment: The `subtasks` form field is not the part of the `Task` model's fields so you have to handle it by youself.  Override `TaskForm.save()` method and save subtasks from the `self.cleaned_data['subtasks']` list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69395/discussion-between-pureferret-and-catavaran).